# Managing data struture state on multithreaded application

Tags: java, multithreading, ip-address

I need some advice on how to manage state of hash map/Array list when it comes to service running on server. I am trying designing IP address management system in which requirement is when ever API call happens, method should provide first available which is not been allocated IP address from the hash map/Array list. I considered two approaches for this.

1. When ever IP address is allocated to some logical name, default.property file is created for that particular IP address/logical name which stores all information. So each time request comes I can go through all files to check what IP addresses are assigned previously and than allocate IP address. But I think this will increase processing time.
2. I can maintain data structure which will have all available IP addresses ad I will stores that object in a file each time ip address is allocated. But I feel this will lead to single point of failure.

It will be great if any one can advice me on this

Thanks for your time.

Comment: At a bit of a loss why are you using files at all. Unless there's something you haven't said like your threads stay alive after your service dies, I don't get it.

Comment: I am planning to use zookeeper which has similar znode structure like folder structure which is why I am initially building a prototype using folders.

Comment: Right oh, don't think there's a right answer to this. If it were me though, I'd go for individual files interms or knowing what's allocated, But I'd have the thread manage it's own file and the server use them. HtHs

Comment: Thanks Tony. I understand its bit requirement dependent. Could you please elaborate why you will select file based approach even tthough it might take more processing time?

Comment: Robustness. If the thread's manage the file create it, lock it on start, and delete it on destroy/close. What's going on is really in your face. Getting the next slot is something you can optimise in several ways, and you wouldn't get any responsiveness issues unless you maxed out your slots. If you got the thread to request a slot from the server, and to release it back....